SharePoint REST API Request for Files returns File Count of folder but returns empty array when files requested
I am having problems returning a list of files in a SharePoint Folder using Postman and the SharePoint REST API's. I am following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest.

My Authorization Token Get Request is configured as below. I successfully return a token so believe this section to be correct
GET REQUEST: https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/a9xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-
xxxxxxxxxxx9/tokens/OAuth/2




I successfully request folder properties using GET https://mxxxxxxxxxxe.sharepoint.com/teams/gdp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL('IFS8')

(Note there are actually 2 files in this folder and the response returns a count of 2 which is also proof this is working)
{
    "Exists": true,
    "ExistsAllowThrowForPolicyFailures": true,
    "ExistsWithException": true,
    "IsWOPIEnabled": false,
    "ItemCount": 2,
    "Name": "IFS8",
    "ProgID": null,
    "ServerRelativeUrl": "/teams/GDP/IFS8",
    "TimeCreated": "2024-03-25T08:17:06Z",
    "TimeLastModified": "2024-04-15T10:13:02Z",
    "UniqueId": "50xxxx4c-3xxx-4xx5-axx2-1adxxxxxe11f",
    "WelcomePage": ""
}


However, when I add "/Files" onto the end of the GET request as per the documentation using:
GET https://mxxxxxxxxxxe.sharepoint.com/teams/gdp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL('IFS8')/Files


I receive this response
{
    "value": []
}

Why am I not being returned the details of each file?
